# How to handle a custom protocol on Blackberry

Tags: url, blackberry, protocols, handler

I'm trying to integrate my application with the web browser on Blackberry platform: the application should be registered as the default handler for a custom protocol (something like "myapp://link-to-resource")

How do I implement it? Is it possible in the first place?

Comment: This question was discussed on official RIM support forum. Check this lik: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-Protocol-Handler/td-p/335240

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to implement it now in my application, I already got the pattern matching part working, but launching the application from the string pattern matcher doesn't work properly (simulator deadlocks). I couldn't find any good examples.